# Escape key function instead of button onclick

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have Escape key function code, Please suggest how to execute instead of button onclick the same function. Kindly suggest.

```js
//escape key function
Brav1Toolbox.addListener(window, "keyup", onKeyUp);
function onKeyUp(e) {
//code
}
```

Answer (score 2):

What you're looking for are known as [**keyCodes**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode). The <kbd>escape</kbd> key is keyCode `27`. Simply run a conditional that checks that keyCode `27` is pressed:

```js
// Escape key function
Brav1Toolbox.addListener(window, "keyup", onKeyUp);

function onKeyUp(e) {
  const keyCode = e.key || e.keyIdentifier || e.keyCode;
  if (keyCode === 27) {
    console.log("Escape was pressed");
  }
}
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: @Ahmad Bamieh, you need to also update the parameter name of the `onKeyUp` function to `event` in your edit.

Comment: @AhmadBamieh Need to add `|| keyCode == 'Escape'`

Comment: Pls, No need to escape key code function, When mouse click "button" that time kecode=27 need to run.

Answer (score 1):

Use `window.onkeydown` and `keyCode`.

```js
window.onkeydown = function(e) {
  var keyCode = e.key || e.keyIdentifier || e.keyCode;
  if (keyCode == 27 || keyCode == 'Escape') {
    alert("The ESC key was pressed!");
    change_screen(27); //Run function
  }
}
```

Comment: request to need to, <div onclick="change_screen(27)" class="b1">CLICK</div> How to write the escape function to click event

Comment: I need to reverse order,
if (e==27){ e.keyCode=27 will be executed }
It is posible

Comment: You can do that. However, it gets [pretty interesting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/596481/is-it-possible-to-simulate-key-press-events-programmatically). I would recommend running the function that is triggered when "ESC" is pressed.

Comment: Pls, No need to escape key code function, When mouse click "button" that time kecode=27 need to run.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
window.addEventListener('keydown', function(e){
    if((e.key=='Escape'||e.key=='Esc'||e.keyCode==27) && (e.target.nodeName=='BODY')){
        console.log("Escape pressed");
        return false;
    }
}, true);
```